# Azure - How SQL Server billing works when VM is deallocated

Tags: azure

We have configured a Windows VM with the following configuration on Azure.

1. VM[Standard DS2 v2 (2 cores, 7 GB memory)]
2. SQL Server Enterprise Edition.

Let's say, I stop the VM (deallocated). I understand that I don't need to pay for the Compute hours. However, I would have to pay for the storage, IPAddress etc. My Question is, Do I need to pay for SQL Server? If Yes, then, Is there a way that I can skip those SQL Server costs?

Comment: This isn't a programming question, and is off-topic for StackOverflow. But... why would you think there's a per-hour license cost for SQL Server?

Comment: Because we have been charged. I also raised a ticket in the azure portal and got a call from Azure billing department (after posting the question) and they confirm that it is charged only for sql license only.

Comment: Yeah - I got e-mail confirmation as well. Here is what they say..• Resolution :   I spoke to you on call and explained that for SQL license the charges are and the windows VM which it runs on charges are different and when VM is in de-allocated status only VM charges are stopped but you will be still charged for the SQL license

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like, Microsoft charge us for SQL Server License (depending on the number of CPU Cores) even if the VM is stopped (Deallocated).

Below is a screen capture of the official e-mail from Azure Support Team.
[image]

Hope this helps someone!

Thanks,
Prawin

Comment: The Azure Pricing Calculator calculates a VM with SQL License per hour. Now I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

If the status says “Stopped (Deallocated)”, you aren’t being billed. If it says “Stopped Allocated”, you’re still being billed for allocated virtual cores (not the software licence itself).

When the State is 'Starting', 'Running' or 'Stopped' (for example Shutdown from within the OS), you are billed. When the state is 'Stopped Deallocated' you are not billed.

The Azure Pricing Calculator also shows you are charged by hour, given the above.

[Pricing SQL Server](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/virtual-machines/sql-server-enterprise/)

Answer (score -1):

Based on below explanation there is no charge even for the license (sql server) if the VM is stopped. Check the FAQ.

*If the status says “Stopped (Deallocated),” you’re not being billed. If it says “Stopped Allocated,” you’re still being billed for allocated virtual cores (not the software license itself)*

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/#Sql

Comment: Sorry Gopi ;-( It doesn't apply for SQL Server unfortunately. Please see my answer below.